# Postfix/Dovecot don't use pam_mkhomedir

Tags: postfix, pam, dovecot

I have users in external database. So far - ssh, postfix, dovecot and some others - use entries with no problem.
I have *Maildirs* inside */home/[user]* and if the homedir exists - everything is ok - sending, receiving.
If homedir does not exist *Postfix/Dovecot* prints error, ssh - after login results in brand new homedir made - it uses **pam_mkhomedir.so** entry in /etc/pam.d/[in few files].
*Postfix/Dovecot* - successfully use **pam.d** with database backend but ignores entries with **pam_mkhomedir** - I have read a lot of hints in which file and on what position place it.
Maybe it's a matter of nameing file /etc/pam.d/[file] ??

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you want. Can you give more informations and examples? You are only telling "it does not work".

Comment: I want Postfix be able to create homedirs for the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix is not responsible for creating home directories. Postfix assumes that the home directories already exist when using the built-in `local` delivery agent.

If you instead use Dovecot as the LDA then Dovecot also relies on the fact that the home directory exists.

With virtual users you can set the variable `lda_mailbox_autocreate = yes` so that Dovecot automatically creates the necessary directories.

---

And as Dovecot (and Postfix) do not "log-in" a user for mail delivery, the `pam_mkhomedir` never gets triggered. PAM is only used for authentication in this case.

Comment: If you allow me that comment: in my opinion, it is not for Postfix or you to decide who is responsible to create home directories. -- The administrator should decide. And the desire to delegate it to the local delivery agent is reasonable to me. Especially if the homedir forms part of the mail infrastructure.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the benefit of others who stumble upon this by googling the Dovecot issue like I just happened to: Dovecot can be made to use `pam_mkhomedir` if you set it up that way. The documentation is at http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/PAM#PAM_sessions

On a typical Debian/Ubuntu system, you can put this in `/etc/pam.d/dovecot`:

```
#%PAM-1.0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

(The `mkhomedir` module is invoked inside `common-session`)

And then edit `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-system.conf.ext` in the section saying:

```
passdb {
  driver = pam
  # [session=yes] ...
  #args = dovecot
}
```

to have those `args` say:

```
  args = session=yes dovecot
```